# How to tell a recruiter you are interested in another position in their company

Tags: interviewing, career-development, job-change

I have searched online for advice. I can only relate [this](http://www.city-data.com/forum/job-search/1524060-how-tell-recruiter-im-not-interested.html) to my situation.

**Background**

- I'm a senior software developer in a medium-sized company.
- In my current position I'm exposed to various kinds of technologies as well as business/client meetings, and mentoring and leading my juniors.
- Basically I enjoy that I get more involved in business decisions. Although I enjoy coding it is not what I want to spend all my day doing.
- I would like to make a transition to be a development manager as the next step in my career.
- I do not mind continuing working as a software developer until I grab a chance to be a manager.
- I'm not sure when will I be promoted to a manager in my company. So I started applying for software developer positions in other companies, mainly for salary increase (my logic is, if I'm not promoted to manager position, at lease I will increase my salary meanwhile).
- One of the very big companies invited me for a software developer position interview. The position technically narrow, though deep, and has zero management exposure.
- I accepted the interview invitation by saying on the phone I am coming for the interview
- Upon further research on the company and the position, I found another opening 'Development Manager'. Although the requirements include min 4 years of management experience (which formally I have nothing of), I am very keen on that position.

**Question:**

- **How** to inform the recruiter (HR consultant works for the company), that I am more interested in that position, given that my qualifications might not meet all the requirements, but definitely I am more project management and business oriented than techie person.
- **When** can I tell? Should I apply for that position and send an email informing him? Or tell that during the interview? Or after the interview?

**Update**
I followed the advice in the answer and sent an email expressing my interest in Manager position, and if it is taken, then I am still interested in the developer position- I applied for the position as well. I did not get any email back, but few hours before my interview I received auto mail informing me that I was rejected for the Manager position. I went for the interview and it was all about development. In fact the interviewer was reiterating that there will be small chance of management position in the coming years. And asked what would I do, and if I would leave the company looking for management position. I replied that I will act as a manager until I become one (take responsibilities and the like). However I also made it clear that it is my ambition to be a manager, and few years is very long time. They might not contact me again for this reason, but at least I am satisfied. I won't sacrifice managememt possibility with my current employer, for mere salary increase.

Comment: Can't you just call/email and say you've seen this position? Alternatively if the recruiter isn't involved with that position can't you just apply for it directly if there is a job advert for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best way to inform the HR consultant about this is by being direct: just send him/her an email (or give a call, if that's the way you are communicating) and explain you've seen another position which might be more adequate to you according to your opinion, orientation and professional goals, even though you don't meet all the requirements. 
If I were you, I'd also mention you are still interested in the Software Developer position if the Development Manager one is already taken or if they don't think you are the right candidate for it.

If the HR consultant is not involved with the Development Manager position, you could let him/her know you are also going to apply for it.

Regarding "when", I'd suggest doing that ASAP, in order to reduce any potential waste of time, both for you and them.

Comment: Welcome to the site Charmander, congratulations on writing a good first answer.

Comment: I'd say give them a call, you're going to get some followup questions for sure and it'd be good to be able to have a dialog with them about it.